# What's the difference between <button>Click Me!</button> and <button type="button">Click Me!</button>?

Tags: html, button, tags

I come across two following code snippets :

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("demo");
  x.style.fontSize = "25px";
  x.style.color = "red";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Click the button to change the layout of this paragraph</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click Me!</button>
```

```html
<h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = Date()"> Click me to display Date and Time.</button>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

I am not able to understand why the different type="button" attribute has been added in second code snippet?

What's the difference between two buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples the addition of the `type="button"` makes no difference whatsoever (remove it and you'll see).

Typically you would specify the `type` of your button if it is being used in a form, as the default `type` of `<button>` is `submit`, and clicking it would cause a `<form>` to be submitted, and typically either reload the current page or load a new page.

By specifying the type as `button` instead of the default `submit`, you prevent that behavior.

Comment: Suppose, I've added a button to a form without adding the 'type' attribute. Do you mean I've to add type="button" if I don't want to submit the form upon clicking it? and if I want to submit the form then there is no need to specify 'type' attribute in a button tag? and use of 'type' attribute in above two code snippets is immaterial?

Comment: Yes to everything in your comment

Answer (score 1):

The `<button>` tag defines a clickable button.

Inside a `<button>` element you can put content, like text or images. This is the difference between this element and buttons created with the `<input>` element.

It has so many Attributes and `type` is one of them and this type has 3 values:

1. `button` (Normal button)
2. `reset` (to handle reset action, specially for form)
3. `submit` (to handle form submit)

To know other properties you can read:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Comment: `<button>` has been around for quite some time; well before HTML5

Answer (score 0):

The attribute `type` decide the style of `<Button>`. It's default value is `button` in Internet Explorer.However, in other browser,it's default value is `submit` even in standard of `W3C`.
So you need to define the `type` of `button` always.

Comment: It _was_ the default in IE, long ago (that is, IE7 and below). These days it's safe to omit the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

**There are three types of buttons:**

1. submit — Submits the current form data. (This is default.)
2. reset — Resets data in the current form.
3. button — Just a button. Its effects must be controlled by something else (that is, with JavaScript).

*Button attribute is not that big deal*, because it changes nothing in your code.
The only difference in your two code versions are writing the whole code after the "onclick" attribute (code2) and writing the function name after the "onlick" attribute (code1).
You can read about the button attributes and differences between input and button with the same attributes on this site http://html.com/attributes/button-type/
I hope it will help you a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Writing `<button type="button">` defines the button as a clickable button.

There is no big difference with `<button>`, but it is more safe to put a type attribute to the button element because some browsers may use different default types for the `<button>` element, which could lead to bugs.